# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser get image errors

Tags: php, html, css

I try to download all image from the specified URL, using Simple HTML DOM Parser. 
It can get image successfully to my folder (I already created folder "hinh" before), but after that, it still returns many error about `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`.

The errors return to my screen:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in D:\xampp\htdocs\cra\index.php on line 11

Warning: file_put_contents(hinh/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\cra\index.php on line 11
```

I already created folder "hinh" before, but it still have an error. This is my code:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php'); //using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to get element in your link
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    //Because I want to make it visible to get multiple links, so I have designed a simple form to input your link. If you click on button, it will do job inside brackets, else do nothing. To make sure it work perfectly, you should check either $_POST['Url']. 
    $url=file_get_html($_POST['url']); //Here I get parameter at textfield to get URL
    $image = $url->find("img"); // Find all <img> tag in your link 
    foreach($image as $img) //Reach to every single line <img> in the destination link
    {
        $s=$img->src; //Get link of image

        $img_name = 'hinh/'.basename($s); //The important step in here. If you want to get file name of image and parse it to fuction save it to your disk (or host, of course!), you have to get file name of it, not a link.      
        file_put_contents($img_name, file_get_contents($s)); //Catch image and store it into place that specified before.
    }
    }   
?>
```

And this is `index.php`

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
  <table width="700" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><label for="textfield"></label>
      <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="url" id="textfield" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: What `var_dump($s)` returns ?

Comment: edit your php.ini file to allow.

Comment: I just already edit my question with an errors unexpected. I run this tool in my localhost with XAMPP tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are handling each image URL as an absolute URL. Let's imagine that the page you're scraping is at http://example.com/pages/index.html.

This works: `<img src="http://example.com/images/1.jpg" />` which resolves to `http://example.com/images/1.jpg` in the browser and `http://example.com/images/1.jpg` in the code.

This doesn't work: `<img src="/images/1.jpg" />` which resolves to `http://example.com/images/1.jpg` in the browser and `/images/1.jpg` in the code.

You have to check whether the image src contains a relative or an absolute URL. Otherwise you'll be searching your filesystem for the image, and this can possibly compromise sensitive data (e.g. `<img src="/etc/shadow" />`).

EDIT:

In the example page, there are img tags with empty src attributes which are loaded using javascript. You can skip these like this:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $url=file_get_html($_POST['url']);
        $image = $url->find("img");
        foreach($image as $img) {
            if(!empty($img->src)) {
                $s=$img->src;
                $img_name = 'hinh/'.basename($s);
                file_put_contents($img_name, file_get_contents($s));
            }
        }
    }   
?>
```

Note that while testing, I discovered that in some cases simple html dom can't load a remote file, it's designed to load local files so I used this instead, it might be a more stable solution:

```
$html  = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
$url   = str_get_html($html);
$image = $url->find("img");
...
```

Comment: You didn't understand what I mean. Everything has fine, I can get all image from specified url. But an error appear when it try to display image to browser.

Comment: This is errors I got: Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in D:\xampp\htdocs\cra\index.php on line 11

Warning: file_put_contents(hinh/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\cra\index.php on line 11

Comment: Those errors are not related to displaying the image, they're related to saving the image. It can't parse a filename from the img tag's src parameter, which is that causes the first error, and it can't put a file into a directory, which causes the second error. Can you share the URL you're trying to parse?

Comment: Yes, sure. I test with this link: http://kenh14.vn/loat-khoanh-khac-dep-den-kho-roi-mat-cua-celine-farach-tren-san-khau-tong-duyet-20170430182719897.chn

Comment: But image still get into my folder named "hinh". All of them.

Comment: Apparently some images are loaded with Javascript on that page, and their src attribute is empty. In this page the answer is not relevant, but that's not the case with all pages. I'll update the answer with a fix for this specific case.

Comment: Thank you. I really don't know what things to do next about this error.

Comment: Thank @onik so much. Now it work for this test case.